# Grouping Keys and Values in Map

Tags: java, collections

I have a Map which has String as key and String[] as value.

```
Map<String,String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("String1", new String[]{ "abc", "dfe", "new"});
map.put("String8", new String[]{"xyz","hji","new"});
map.put("String2", new String[]{"abc","dfe","old"});
map.put("String3", new String[]{"abc","dfe","past"});
map.put("String5", new String[]{"xyz","hji","ancient"});
map.put("String6",new String[]{"xyz","hji","past"});
map.put("String4", new String[]{"abc","dfe","ancient"});
map.put("String7", new String[]{"xyz","hji","old"});
```

I want to print map grouping using values. 
Value is array of String. 
First two elements of String array will be used for grouping.
The code has to find similar values and group by values without passing any filter.
Final output will be like bellow:

```
String1:[{ "abc", "dfe", "new"}]
String2:[{"abc","dfe","old"}]
String3:[{"abc","dfe","past"}]
String4:[{"abc","dfe","ancient"}]
String5:[{"xyz","hji","ancient"}]
String6:[{"xyz","hji","past"}]
String7:[{"xyz","hji","old"}]
String8:[{"xyz","hji","new"}]
```

How to accomplish this in Java 8?

Comment: Use ```TreeMap``` rather than ```HashMap```; it will sort the items based on key, then you can just iterate over the key set.

Comment: Also prefer `List<String>` over `String[]` in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output it appears you just want to sort based on the key. So you can do this.  Create a `SortedMap` and just add the current map to it in the constructor.

```
SortedMap<String,String[]> smap = new TreeMap<>(map);
smap.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k + ":" + Arrays.toString(v)));
```

Prints

```
String1:[abc, dfe, new]
String2:[abc, dfe, old]
String3:[abc, dfe, past]
String4:[abc, dfe, ancient]
String5:[xyz, hji, ancient]
String6:[xyz, hji, past]
String7:[xyz, hji, old]
String8:[xyz, hji, new]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do double grouping by like this :

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("String1", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "new"});
map.put("String8", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "new"});
map.put("String2", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "old"});
map.put("String3", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "past"});
map.put("String5", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "ancient"});
map.put("String6", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "past"});
map.put("String4", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "ancient"});
map.put("String7", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "old"});


Map<String, Map<String, List<Map.Entry<String, String[]>>>> collect = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getValue()[0], Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getValue()[1])));

Map<String, String[]> collect1 = collect.values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(x -> x.values().stream())
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(collect1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort based on keys then you can do it by using Java 8:

```
        Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("String1", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "new"});
        map.put("String8", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "new"});
        map.put("String2", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "old"});
        map.put("String3", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "past"});
        map.put("String5", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "ancient"});
        map.put("String6", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "past"});
        map.put("String4", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "ancient"});
        map.put("String7", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "old"});

        map = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(comparingByKey()).collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));

        map.forEach((s1, strings) -> System.out.println(s1 + " : " + Arrays.toString(strings)));
```

Output Will be:

```
String1 : [abc, dfe, new]
String2 : [abc, dfe, old]
String3 : [abc, dfe, past]
String4 : [abc, dfe, ancient]
String5 : [xyz, hji, ancient]
String6 : [xyz, hji, past]
String7 : [xyz, hji, old]
String8 : [xyz, hji, new]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also as you mentioned you want to sort map based on 1st 2 element of array (Value) then you can try Comparator:

**Grouping 1st 2 elements of array from value then sorting**:

```
    Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("String1", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "new"});
    map.put("String8", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "new"});
    map.put("String2", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "old"});
    map.put("String3", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "past"});
    map.put("String5", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "ancient"});
    map.put("String6", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "past"});
    map.put("String4", new String[]{"abc", "dfe", "ancient"});
    map.put("String7", new String[]{"xyz", "hji", "old"});

    // Compare based on 1st 2 element oof Array (Map Value)
    Comparator<String[]> byArrayValue = (String[] o1, String[] o2) -> o1[0].concat(o1[1]).compareTo(o2[0].concat(o2[1]));


    // Sort based on 1st 2 element of array
    map = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, String[]>comparingByValue(byArrayValue))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));


    map.forEach((s1, strings) -> System.out.println(s1 + " : " + String.join(",", strings)));
```

Output Will be based on 1st 2 element of value array:

```
String4 : [abc, dfe, ancient]
String3 : [abc, dfe, past]
String2 : [abc, dfe, old]
String1 : [abc, dfe, new]
String8 : [xyz, hji, new]
String7 : [xyz, hji, old]
String6 : [xyz, hji, past]
String5 : [xyz, hji, ancient]
```